# Adding multiple Cocoapods to one Xcode project

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I wanted to add multiple Cocoapods into one Xcode application, is this possible?

Is downloading multiple Pods in one Xcode project recommended?

Comment: Your project is in swift or obj-c? Why you want to use the bridging header? Did you searched anything about the pods?

Comment: My project is in swift.

Comment: mention required pod name in "Podfile" and update pod using terminal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes you can install multiple cocoapods by adding the name of the pods in PODFILE and then run the update code in terminal and you only need to create one bridging header and that you will need to import all the imports of the cocoapods which are necessary

Comment: Thanks! Do i have to add all the pods at the same time, or can i add one then add another one later?

Comment: You can add according to your requirement, if you want to install more than one at the same time or one after another according to the requirement then also its ok. There is no harm in adding multiple pods at the same time

Answer (score 5):

The Pod file which you have created in the project, open it and add the pods

```
platform :ios, "8.0"
use_frameworks! 

target 'ProjectName' do

pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.9.0'
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.0'
// go on adding whatever pods you want to integrate

end
```